# cannot execute binary file python on mac local machine

Tags: mac, terminal, python, amazon-web-services

`python --version` shows that I have version 2.7.10 installed on my mac, it's located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` trying to execute python from terminal raised the error: `cannot execute binary file`

I'm trying to execute it like so hopping to successfully install `awscli`, that is failing while its trying to uninstall python resulting in `Operation not permitted` (obviously) and crashing --> [aws](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) states that if an existing version of python exist there is an option to install `awscli` specifically with it.

Comment: When you run `python --version` in your shell, and you can see the version, it means that it runs fine. Please specifiy the exact command which you enter, that produces that error message. Also specify which shell you are running.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you’re trying to run the pre-installed Python interpreter on a Mac.  There should be a `python` binary in `/usr/bin` — this is what you should be trying to execute.  `/usr/bin` *should* be in your `$PATH`, so you should just be able to type…

```
python
```

… at the shell prompt.

If that doesn’t work, check whether `/user/bin` is in your `$PATH`, and add it if it isn’t.

Comment: Why does it give the error in the first place.